# UNION ALL and LIMIT in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Let's say I want to perform this query:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT a FROM t3 WHERE a=12 AND B=3) 
ORDER BY a LIMIT 1000;
```

Is MySQL smart enough to skip "t3" if 550 results are available in "t1" and 450 in "t2"?

I'm looking at MySQL docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) but can't seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified in UNION Syntax description (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html):

> The default behavior for UNION is that
>   duplicate rows are removed from the
>   result. The optional DISTINCT keyword
>   has no effect other than the default
>   because it also specifies
>   duplicate-row removal. With the
>   optional ALL keyword, duplicate-row
>   removal does not occur and the result
>   includes all matching rows from all
>   the SELECT statements.

I suppose, that's the answer to your question.

Comment: In the result set, does data from t1 will always be before t2 and t3 and t2 before t3? I need to read the data ordered by "B ASC" and wondering if I can skip the "order by B ASC" following the unions.

Comment: Is specified in manual, "UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows", so, as far as I understand, there's no guarantee.

Comment: @Kel Please, advice what happens if at first use `LIMIT 0,5` and on second query, for example, `LIMIT 5,10`? Unordered set of rows, but i hope with `LIMIT 5,10` there will be no rows that where with `LIMIT 0,5`? Unordered, but i hope the same order for all queries?

Comment: As i tested http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09b72b/6 seems `UNION` always creates temporary table with the same order of results. And with different `LIMIT` i will get unique (not duplicate) results.

Answer (score 17):

Currently, MySQL will perform all selects on a union even if there are enough rows in the first few queries, as @Yuki Inoue mentioned in their answer. Using @user1477929's answer, you could re-write your query as:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 LIMIT 1000) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 LIMIT 1000) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT a FROM t3 WHERE a=12 AND B=3 LIMIT 1000) 
ORDER BY a LIMIT 1000;
```

which will give you at most 1000 rows, and never scan more than 3000.

Comment: What happens if `ORDER BY a LIMIT 500,1000` ? Mysql creates temporary table with 3000 results (maximum) from the three tables and then from temporary table takes 501st row? Or something else?

Answer (score 5):

It works for me I'm using MySQL.

but make sure the limit number is always the same for all

*in that example it gets you 3 results from each table*

```
 (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 LIMIT 9) 
 UNION ALL 
 (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 LIMIT 9) 
 UNION ALL 
 (SELECT a FROM t3 WHERE a=12 AND B=3 LIMIT 9)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a very large table, then you can execute following query to see how smart MySQL optimizer is...

```
(
  select * from very_large_table
  union all
  select * from very_large_table
) limit 1
```

Sadly, this query takes very long time, compared to following query.

```
select * from very_large_table limit 1
```

It seems that whenever result of `UNION` is needed, MySQL first calculates the entire temporary table of the UNION result.

#### version

- MySQL 8.0.11

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MySql is smart enough to skip `t3` if the results returned from `t1` and `t2` are equal to the `LIMIT`. In fact, it's the default behavior.