# MySQL Optimize UNION query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, union, explain

I'm trying to optimize a query.

My question seems to be similar to [MySQL, Union ALL and LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008486/mysql-union-all-and-limit) and the answer might be the same (I'm afraid). However in my case there's a stricter limit (1) as well as an index on a datetime column.

So here we go:

For simplicity, let's have just one table with three: columns:

- md5 (varchar)
- value (varchar).
- lastupdated (datetime)

There's an index on (md5, updated) so selecting on a md5 key, ordering by updated and limiting to 1 will be optimized.

The search shall return a maximum of one record matching one of 10 md5 keys. The keys have a priority. So if there's a record with prio 1 it will be preferred over any record with prio 2, 3 etc.

Currently UNION ALL is used:

```
select * from

(

(
select 0 prio, value
from mytable
where md5 = '7b76e7c87e1e697d08300fd9058ed1db'
order by lastupdated desc 
limit 1
)

union all

(
select 1 prio, value
from mytable
where md5 = 'eb36cd1c563ffedc6adaf8b74c259723'
order by lastupdated desc 
limit 1
)

) x

order by prio
limit 1;
```

It works, but the UNION seems to execute all 10 queries if 10 keys are provided.

However, from a business perspective, it would be ok to run the selects sequentially and stop after the first match.

Is that possible though plain SQL?

Or would the only option be a stored procedure?

Comment: Union ALL doesn't use Index so I don't think you can optimize too much.

Comment: How is priority determined?

Comment: Charles - thanks. Currently, the priority is defined by the application itself. Theoretically it's dynamic, but in reality it's "more or less" static, so it could go to the database (actually see my one of my comments below). I'll try to put the prio in the database and use an index+limit+order by

Answer (score 0):

There's a much better way to do this that doesn't need UNION.  You really want the groupwise max for each key, with a custom ordering.

[Groupwise Max](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

[Order by FIELD()](http://jonahellison.com/mysql-order-by-field-group_concat)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way the optimizer for `UNION ALL` can figure out what you're up to.

I don't know if you can do this, but suppose you had a md5prio table with the list of hash codes you know you're looking for.  For example.

```
prio   md5
0      '7b76e7c87e1e697d08300fd9058ed1db'
1      'eb36cd1c563ffedc6adaf8b74c259723'
etc
```

in it.

Then your query could be:

```
    select mytable.*
      from mytable
      join md5prio on mytable.md5 = md5prio.md5
  order by md5prio.prio, mytable.lastupdated desc
     limit 1
```

This might save the repeated queries.  You'll definitely need your index on mytable.md5. I am not sure whether your compound index on lastupdated will help; you'll need to try it.

Comment: Ollie - Thanks - actually the design is that the priorities may change at runtime, that's why they are provided in the query.

Comment: Ollie - maybe you're right. The tables can probably be restructured so that we have the priority somewhere in the database with an index, and  the application can just use an index with limit+order by without any UNION magic. We'll see tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the most efficient solution may be to build an index on `(md5, lastupdated)`.  This index should be used to resolve each subquery very efficiently (looking up the values in the index and then looking up one data page).

Unfortunately, the groupwise max referenced by Gavin will produce multiple rows when there are duplicate lastupdated values (admittedly, perhaps not a concern in your case).

There is, actually, a MySQL way to get this answer, using `group_concat` and `substring_index`:

```
select p.prio,
       substring_index(group_concat(mt.value order by mt.lastupdated desc), ',', 1)
from mytable mt join
     (select 0 as prio, '7b76e7c87e1e697d08300fd9058ed1db' as md5 union all
      select 1 as prio, 'eb36cd1c563ffedc6adaf8b74c259723' as md5 union all
      . . .
     ) p
     on mt.md5 = p.md5
```

Comment: Gordon - thanks. But still each select in the UNION would be executed separately, right? That's what I'm trying to avoid, but it seems UNION cannot be influenced that way.

Comment: @user1946784 . . . In the first example with the index, each select is done separately, but highly efficiently.  The table is not being read; only one record from the index and the associated page.  In the second example, `mytable` would either be scanned or it would need an index on `md5`.