# How to display top 5 and bottom 5 in same query with join?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm struggling to find a way to combine these two queries into one so that only one table is viewed.  I want to display the top 5 and bottom 5 categories based on the number of members in each category.

```
SELECT 
    category_name,
    members
From category c
JOIN grp g ON c.category_id=g.category_id
GROUP by category_name
ORDER BY members DESC
LIMIT 5;

SELECT 
    category_name,
    members
From category c
JOIN grp g ON c.category_id=g.category_id
GROUP by category_name
ORDER BY members
LIMIT 5;
```

I've tried union and multiple select statements but always end up with an error for "subquery returns more than 1 row" or inccorect syntax.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is: use `UNION`, or `UNION ALL`.  I wonder what you did when you got the error.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15024011/724039

Comment: I removed "MYSQL Work Bench" from the title. Because MYSQL Work Bench is a tool to connect to a MySQL database, and should not have influence on the syntax of a SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to do unions with `ORDER` and `LIMIT` clauses, you will have to "hide" these clauses within subqueries:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        category_name,
        members
    From category c
    JOIN grp g ON c.category_id=g.category_id
    GROUP by category_name
    ORDER BY members DESC
    LIMIT 5
) SQ1
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        category_name,
        members
    From category c
    JOIN grp g ON c.category_id=g.category_id
    GROUP by category_name
    ORDER BY members
    LIMIT 5
) SQ2
```

Comment: That worked. I think i was missing the second sellect * after the union.  Instead of using a union, how would you display these side by side?

Comment: You should open up a *new* question and explain more clearly what "side by side* would look like because right now I would only be guessing as to what you are looking for. But  be sure to specify which release of MySQL you have because the solution will probably depend on that.

Comment: Thanks. Will do.  Unfortunately, I'll have to wait since my original question got downvoted.